# problem with sign wallet for use in substrate and nodejs : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'specVersion')

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template

i wanna to craete wallet for user in nodejs and substrate . i using these codes for connect to substrate node and create a wallet :

```
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');
const { Keyring } = require('@polkadot/keyring');
const { cryptoWaitReady, mnemonicGenerate, mnemonicToMiniSecret, schnorrkelKeypairFromSeed } = require('@polkadot/util-crypto');
const { TypeRegistry } = require('@polkadot/types'); // Add this import

class PolkadotWrapper {
  constructor(endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    this.api = null;
  }

  async connect() {
    const wsProvider = new WsProvider(this.endpoint);
    const registry = new TypeRegistry();
  
    this.api = await ApiPromise.create({
      provider: wsProvider,
      registry, 
      types: {}, 
    });
  
    await this.api.isReady;
  }
  

  createAccount() {
    const mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate();
    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
    const newAccount = keyring.createFromUri(mnemonic);
  
    return {
      instance: newAccount, 
      mnemonic,
      address: newAccount.address,
      publicKey: newAccount.publicKey.toString('hex'),
    };
  }
  

and it create a wallet for user but when i need to call this function whith that created account with `createAccount` function : 

  const newAccount = wrapper.createAccount();
  console.log('New account:', newAccount.instance);
```

transafer function :

```
  async transfer(fromAccount, toAddress, amount) {
    if (!this.api) throw new Error('API not connected');

    // Prepare the extrinsic
    const extrinsic = this.api.tx.balances.transfer(toAddress, amount);

    // Sign and send the extrinsic
    const { nonce } = await this.api.query.system.account(fromAccount.address);
    const signedExtrinsic = extrinsic.sign(fromAccount, { nonce });

    // Submit the transaction and return the result
    const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      signedExtrinsic.send(({ status, events }) => {
        if (status.isInBlock || status.isFinalized) {
          events.forEach(({ event }) => {
            if (event.section === 'system' && event.method === 'ExtrinsicFailed') {
              reject(new Error('Extrinsic failed'));
            } else if (event.section === 'system' && event.method === 'ExtrinsicSuccess') {
              resolve({ blockHash: status.asInBlock.toHex() });
            }
          });
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });

    return result;
  }
```

it show me this error :

`Transaction failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'specVersion')`

**what the problem ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initializing your API like so:

```js
const wsProvider = new WsProvider(this.endpoint);
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
```

Also, here is some working code that may help you.

```js
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from "@polkadot/api"
import { mnemonicGenerate } from '@polkadot/util-crypto'
import { Keyring } from '@polkadot/keyring';

// const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://rpc.polkadot.io');
const wsProvider = new WsProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:54185");
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });

const mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate();
const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
const brunoPair = keyring.addFromUri(mnemonic, { name: 'Bruno' }, 'sr25519');
console.log(brunoPair.meta.name, 'has address', brunoPair.address);

// For testing purposes
const alicePair = keyring.addFromUri('//Alice');
const bobPair = keyring.addFromUri('//Bob');

export const createAccount = async () => {

    const mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate();
    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });
    const pair = keyring.addFromUri(mnemonic, { name: 'Bruno' }, 'sr25519');
    console.log(pair.meta.name, 'has address', pair.address);

    return {
      pair, 
      mnemonic,
      address: pair.address,
      publicKey: pair.publicKey.toString('hex'),
    };
  }

  console.log(`New account: {}`, await createAccount());

  const transfer = async (fromAccount, toAddress, amount) => {
    
    const { nonce } = await api.query.system.account(fromAccount);

    // You need to get the account from the keyring
    const fromAccountPair = keyring.getPair(fromAccount);

    api.tx.balances.transfer(toAddress, amount).signAndSend(fromAccountPair, { nonce }, ({ events = [], status }) => {
        console.log('Transaction status:', status.type);
  
        if (status.isInBlock) {
          console.log('Included at block hash', status.asInBlock.toHex());
          console.log('Events:');
  
          events.forEach(({ event: { data, method, section }, phase }) => {
            console.log('\t', phase.toString(), `: ${section}.${method}`, data.toString());
          });
        } else if (status.isFinalized) {
          console.log('Finalized block hash', status.asFinalized.toHex());
  
          process.exit(0);
        }
      });
  }

  // transfer from Alice to Bob
  transfer(alicePair.address, bobPair.address, 7000000000000000);
```